# Refresh page and parallely analyze mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on e-commerce project. Book Section has 60,000 books and 37,000 authors in my mysql tables.

here is the link of [book table structure](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvMdP7QR7ksedE9uSDd1LUxCX3BOM1kyaFZqaHVMWFE&hl=en_US)
Book page takes 13 seconds to load-Horrible. I want to know that is there any tool that Give me real time analysis. It mean, I refresh page and I can see total number of queries executed when page load completes. So I can analyze and write time effective queries.

Additionally, Please guide me little for how can I improve mysql performance for such e-commerce project. Project's Index page displays 3-4 items from all section like camera, Apparels, Mobile etc. So in turn fetch from almost all categories.

Please help.

Thank you In advance.

Comment: It would be good to see the table structures and the query you are running, then we can more easily take a look. It may be you need some indexes, or the query may be non-optimal.

Comment: Thank you DaveRix for your attention. As per your request here is the table structure. You can direcly add there your comments. Here is the link Book Table Structure [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvMdP7QR7ksedE9uSDd1LUxCX3BOM1kyaFZqaHVMWFE&hl=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

Are you limiting your result set of the data returned? Please remember to post the query that you are running.